# How can i get just one row where some column values are same in knexjs

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I tried to get distinct values from my table

```
    let records = db
    .select("*")
    .from("user_technical_skill")
    .distinct('technical_skill_id')
```

in the `user_technical_skill` table i have for example

```
[{
"id": "84ed9c04-b1d3-4e69-b2d2-c569ad94545f",
"user_id": "5dfbf2cc-38f9-4388-a077-11480e62d893",
"technical_skill_id": "111",
"created_at": "2021-04-11T15:31:39.552Z",
"updated_at": "2021-04-11T15:31:39.552Z"
},
{
"id": "4b0fcdd6-cbab-4fdf-ada6-0154c7956630",
"user_id": "a3b91e2a-5d7e-4528-b496-3a0807299db7",
"technical_skill_id": "111",
"created_at": "2021-04-11T15:48:49.145Z",
"updated_at": "2021-04-11T15:48:49.145Z"
}]
```

two columns where technical_skill_id is 11

but it does not work. I get again the two columns in my query
How can i fix this ?

Comment: which db is you're using?

Comment: PostgreSql i am using

Comment: Do you need all columns or just user_technical_skill in the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you need all columns you can use group by instead of distinct().

```js
let records = db
    .select("*")
    .from("user_technical_skill")
    .groupBy('technical_skill_id')
```

otherwise if you need just user_technical_skill in the result you can use

```js
let records = db.from("user_technical_skill").distinct('technical_skill_id')
```

you don't need a select("*") since distinct is like a select alternative.

Ref:

- http://knexjs.org/#Builder-distinct
- http://knexjs.org/#Builder-groupBy

Comment: @Thanks for your reply. But i get `"name": "error",
"length": 248,
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "42803",
"position": "8",
"file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_agg.c",
"line": "1409",
"routine": "check_ungrouped_columns_walker"` error when i do this...